# Scala ZIO Stream datatype

Tags: scala, stream, zio

Is there's away to find the size of ZIO Stream ,I have two streams and wanted to find the inner product between the two, my problem is how I can find the size in order to iterate over them . I solved the problem using map and foldMap but I wanted to check performance between two ways ? 
This is my work using Fold and Map :

```
import zio._
import zio.console.{Console, putStrLn}
import zio.stream._
object InnerProduct extends App {

  val stream1: Stream[Nothing, Int] = Stream(1,2,3,4)
  val stream2: Stream[Nothing, Int] = Stream(4,5,6,7)


  def inner_fold [A,B,C,D,E](stream1:Stream[Nothing,A])(stream2:Stream[Nothing,B])(tms: (A, B) => C)(pls: (D, C) => D)(zero: D)= for{
    acc <- Ref.make(zero)
    acc2 <- acc.get
    i = 0
    compStream = stream1.zip(stream2)
    str = compStream.map(i => tms(i._1,i._2))
    streamFold<- str.fold(acc2)(pls)
    _ <-acc.set(streamFold)
  } yield acc

  override def run(args: List[String]) =
    for {
    res <- inner_fold[Int, Int, Int, Int,Int](stream1)(stream2)(_ * _)(_ + _ )(0)
      res2 <-res.get
      _ <- putStrLn(res2.toString)
    } yield (0)

}
```

The output :60

Comment: Please give an example of expected inputs/outputs so that we better understand what you're after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that by "inner product", you mean you have two `Stream[Double]` that you want to consider as mathematical vectors and compute a single output value after iterating over the whole streams.

For this, it is easy to use `zip` to compute the element-wise product of the two streams, and then `foldLeft` to compute the final result.

```scala
val products: Stream[Double] = stream1.zip(stream2).map(_ * _)
val innerProduct: UIO[Double] = products.run(Sink.foldLeft(_ * _))
```

Comment: thanks this is what I have done sofar but I'm searching to use the iteration rather map & flatMap I have some performance issues. 
I did inner product without ZIO style in order to find the best performance using ( For comprehension , ````While```` , ````Map```` ,````Fold```` , Recursion  )

Comment: There will often be a bit of an overhead when using `Stream` over a plain `Array`, because the stream allows you to do the computation asynchronously, on sequences that are very long and where all values are not necessarily accessible from the start. If all your data is available from the start and fits in an `Array`, you will likely get better performance using the `Array` and a `for` loop.

Comment: This is my work https://github.com/naseem91/InnerProduct/blob/master/src/main/scala/InnerProduct.scala
I updated my question with the solution in ZIO

Comment: Ok. If you have benchmark results please share them, I would be interested to see if the difference is large.

Comment: You can see the test in this link but plz make a big size to notice the difference 
https://github.com/naseem91/InnerProduct/blob/master/src/main/scala/InnerProductExamples.scala